# Tikzpicture and draw function producing an uneven line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

In a book document class, using the `tikz` package with the follow libraries: `matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains,calc`

In a matrix of nodes, I am seeing the draw function produce a line that's not straight. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix [matrix of math nodes,column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]
        {
                |(A1)| & |(A2)| t & |(A3)| t \omega & |(A4)| t \omega^2\\
                |(B1)| s & |(B2)| s + t & |(B3)| s + t \omega & |(B4)| s + t \omega^2\\
                |(C1)| s \omega & |(C2)| s \omega + t & |(C3)| s \omega + t \omega & |(C4)| s \omega + t \omega^2\\
                |(D1)| s \omega^2 & |(D2)| s \omega^2 + t & |(D3)| s \omega^2 + t \omega & |(D4)| s \omega^2 + t \omega^2\\
};
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway,auto,font=\scriptsize}]
                \draw[shorten <=-0.25cm,shorten >=-0.25cm] ($(A1)!0.5!(A2)$)--($(D1)!0.5!(D2)$);
                \draw[shorten <=-0.5cm,shorten >=-0.5cm] ($(A1)!0.5!(B1)$)--($(A4)!0.5!(B4)$);
                \draw [red, dashed] (B2) -- node {} (C4);
                \draw [red, dashed] (C4) -- node {} (D3);
                \draw [red, dashed] (B2) -- node {} (D3);
                \draw [blue, dashed] (B3) -- node {} (D4);
                \draw [blue, dashed] (D4) -- node {} (C2);
                \draw [blue, dashed] (C2) -- node {} (B3);
                \draw [green, dashed] (B4) -- node {} (C3);
                \draw [green, dashed] (C3) -- node {} (D2);
        \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The A1 node is empty (by design). But, if i put some text there, like the letter 'x' then the line straightens out. Is there a way to put a blank/dummy place holder in that node? Or, is there a better way to generate this matrix entirely? I must not understand the draw function properly.

[image: Top line is uneven]

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code fragment so that it can be copy-paste-compiled.

Comment: Try `nodes in empty cells` or whatever it is called. (I'd test if I had a working example.)

Comment: Or just specify e.g. `(A1 |- A4)` or whatever, to be certain of getting a horizontal line.

Comment: Placeholders include \phantom{}, \strut, \null, and \rule with one 0pt dimensionj.

Comment: @cfr,  I added those lines but screwed up the formatting of the post. Sorry for the noob mistakes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write your MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, % added matrix name "m"
             nodes in empty cells, % added
             column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]
{
            & t             & t\omega               & t \omega^2            \\[-0.5cm]
s           & s + t         & s + t\omega           & s + t \omega^2        \\
s\omega     & s\omega + t   & s\omega + t\omega     & s\omega + t\omega^2   \\
s\omega^2   & s\omega^2 + t & s\omega^2 + t\omega   & s\omega^2 + t\omega^2 \\
};
%  at all lines is used matrix cells naming system
\draw ($(m-1-1.north)!0.5!(m-1-2.north)$)--($(m-4-1.south)!0.5!(m-4-2.south)$);
\draw ($(m-1-1.west)!0.5!(m-2-1.west)$)--($(m-1-4.east)!0.5!(m-2-4.east)$);
\draw [red, dashed] 
    (m-2-2) -- (m-3-4)
    (m-3-4) -- (m-4-3)
    (m-2-2) -- (m-4-3);
\draw [blue, dashed] 
    (m-2-3) -- (m-4-4)
    (m-4-4) -- (m-3-2)
    (m-3-2) -- (m-2-3);
\draw [green, dashed] 
    (m-2-4) -- (m-3-3)
    (m-3-3) -- (m-4-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

It is not clear why you draw lines for example as `\draw [green, dashed] (C3) -- node {} (D2);`. Addd empty node doesn't harm, but it is surplus, if you will not add some text latter. In this case the library `quotes`  is handy: `\draw [green, dashed] (C3) to["<text>"] (D2);`

Hopefully the code is enough self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite. I can't justify the way I coded my matrix. I took bits and pieces of what I could find online and cobbled it together. I'm marking this as the answer!